# How to make Postgresql query with JQuery in Django?

Tags: jquery, django, postgresql

I need to dynamically change a forum based on a selection of a drop down menu. The forum will have a menu and two textboxes. All the information is in a Postgresql database, like so:

```
 |  Dropdown |  Text1  |  Text 2  |
---------------------------------
 |     1     |   red   |   blue   |
 |     2     |   dog   |    cat   |
```

This this `choice_table`. Now, in my HTML code I have put the following to figure out which choice has been selected:

```
 <script>
        $("#id_drop_down").on('change', function() {
          if ($(this).val() !== ""){
            $choice = $(this).val()
            alert($choice + " has been selected!")
          };
        });
      </script>
```

My next step is to use `$choice` to use as an identifier to query into the `choice_table` and populate `Text1` and  `Text2`.  How can I use `$choice` to query my database?

Comment: What is the backend?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I'm using the Django framework, if that's helpful.

Comment: So you need to write a Django view that your Ajax talks to. Where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a view that handles your ajax calls and returns data in appropriate format, for example JSON. Then, make ajax requests from client html page on this view to get your data.

Comment: I didn't realize that a view handled the ajax information, I thought is was all done in the script XD. Well that's what I'm working on now, got it partly working. Thanks!